# Sending one time event to child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Im struggling to implement something which I think is pretty easy.

In my Vue app I loop through a list. Each list item is a child component. Each list item has an expand/collapse button. That works fine, but I want to be able to close all open items from the parent and I don't seem to be able to get that working as I would like.

The expand/collapse is controlled via a variable called `isOpen` so

```
<div v-if="isOpen">Something here</div>
```

I have tried using a computed property instead of the isOpen and passing props but that issue is I think it needs to act more like an event.

Consider three open list items. If the list items are controlled by a prop, and setting it to `false` closes the items, when an item is reopened, the prop is still `false` so therefore will not work a second time. I know I could change it back on the parent, but it seems wrong.

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you add `open` and `close` methods to your inner component that sets/unsets the `isOpen` flag? The for the expand all you just call the `open` method from each component.

Comment: This should be achievable by simply using props but in case the components are not directly relatived you can always use an event bus. https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Pass an [event bus](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) to each child. Set up the children to respond to a `close` event on the bus. When the parent emits a close event on the bus, all respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you passed an "allClosed" prop, you would need to have your child components emit events to reset it every time they opened. That seems hacky to me. I think you are right that it should be more of a parent-to-children event, which calls for an event bus.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    closeBus: new Vue(),
    kids: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  components: {
    expandableThing: {
      data() {
        return {
          isOpen: true
        }
      },
      props: ['bus'],
      methods: {
        toggle() {
          this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
        }
      },
      created() {
        this.bus.$on('close', () => this.isOpen = false);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <expandable-thing v-for="kid in kids" inline-template :bus="closeBus">
    <div>
      <div v-show="isOpen">My stuff!</div>
      <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
    </div>
  </expandable-thing>
  <button @click="closeBus.$emit('close')">Close all</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers Roy, this looks perfect